# rails: correct redirect but incorrect URL in address bar after creating into DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app, i have a create button as such

```
   def create
      @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
      @inventory = @client.inventories.create(params[:inventory])
      redirect_to client_path(@client)
   end
```

which when an inventory is created (as a part of client, ex. client has_many inventories, inventories belongs_to clients), the inventory is added to the client in the database and it redirects to localhost:3000/client/(whatever the clients ID is)

However, i'm having a problem with my program because although it does the correct redirect, the address in the address bar after i push create is localhost:3000/client/1/inventories/1... and I only want it to be localhost:3000/client/1/ . If I actually do try to access localhost:3000/client/1/inventories/1, it gives me an error because I don't have a show for inventories.

How is it possibly doing the correct redirect, but the wrong URL is displayed in my browser? By the way, this is in my routes.rb, which does not seem like the problem to me.

```
 resources :clients do
    resources :inventories
 end
```

Why is my app behaving like this?  Any takers? :]

**EDIT**

When I type rake routes I see this.
[image: This]
 The routes for create and destroy seem wrong. How do I change them?

Comment: Do you have any before_filters that might be screwing with things? Also, try the rake routes command to see if there is anything unexpected going on...

Comment: It does seem like my rake routes has some unwanted things going on, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is a screenshot of the part I think looks wrong, http://i49.tinypic.com/b51yrk.png . After create, i want it to go to  /clients/client_id/ instead of what it says, /clients/client_id/inventories. and the same thing for destroy, I want it to go to /clients/:clientid/ instead of what it is doing in the screenshot

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your rake routes output, where do you think is the problem in the rake routes output

Comment: It is a problem that the URL in the address bar displays /clients/:client_id/inventories upon a create inventory, because it should go to /clients/:client_id. I am specifically talking about the route for inventories#create and inventories#destroy. I believe this is what is controlling my address bar displaying /clients/client_id/inventories after a create although a redirect is done to client_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to this problem is going to inventories controller and adding

```
 def index
     @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
     redirect_to client_path(@client)
 end
```

Looks like this was the best way to handle the back button hitting these errors, it seems like you cannot control the address displayed in the address bar. At least we don't know how.. :P

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use:

```
redirect_to client_path(@client.id)
```

Comment: this solution does not work for me, it acts the same. i dont believe the error is in this line, because i can redirect to anything and it still goes to  /client/#/inventories. it is being redirected to the right page, just the display is wrong. it does load /client/# . . . but the address bar says /client/#/inventories. this becomes a problem when pushing the back button on the next page, which brings an error page. Unknown action

The action 'index' could not be found for InventoriesController

Comment: So where is the redirecting occurring? Can you post the server log?

Comment: It seems like the redirect is occuring to the correct place, being client_path(@client.id) [localhost:3000/clients/id#/] but the address in the address bar says [localhost:3000/clients/id#/inventory], although that site is not what the browser is rendering. If I do render [localhost:3000/clients/id#/inventory], it gives me the error page. (unknown action blablabla).
here is a screenshot of the server log http://i45.tinypic.com/24w6hzm.jpg